# C Sorting records from a file

Tags: c, file, sorting

Hi Everyone I am working on a project to sort a file with a large quantity of records based on the given criteria (name or age or gender or hometown) and write to the output file in the format of the original file. However I am debating what is the fastest approach to do so. The file contains records such as:

```
Name Age gender hometown
Adam 28  Male   New york
Kevin 42 Male   Boston
...
```

My thought is to read the file and create a linked-list of struct:

```
struct record
{   
char * SortCriteriaString;
int SortCriteriaInt;
char * Name;
int Age;
char * Gender;
char * Hometown;};
```

and then mersort the linked list based on the criteria I read from command line and store in the SortCriteriaInt or SortCriteriaString members of the struct.

Here is what I plan to do with this project. But I was asked to come up with the fastest sorter possible, so my question is: What are the fastest data structure and sorting algorithm for this task if not the one I described above?

Comment: @MitchWheat but if I take the sort criteria as a string from command line, how can I access the member of struct? If copying into the rows of sort criteria makes it slower, is it better to write sorting functions for all the cases?

Comment: It **really** depends on what you would do with that structure later, but I'd personally go for dynamic array and quicksort. If your file size will differ largely, maybe the binary tree is a good approach

Comment: @Fureeish Hi thanks for the feedback! What if I need to go for merge sort? Is linked list a good data structure for fast performance?

Comment: `malloc` and `quicksort` are easiest and fastest, it should be option 1. If you have an old computer from 30 years ago then you will find linked list is slightly faster.

Comment: No. Mergesort is preferred for Linked Lists, but it is so because other sorts are either impossible to implement or really inefficient for this data structure. Your best average performance would be array + quicksort, but if you are stuck using Mergesort, use either of those two. The problem here lies in the fact that Mergesort, in addition to having time complexity of `O(n*log_2(n))`, also uses additional `O(n)` space, thus it will be **really** inefficient in your "*file with a large quantity of records*".

Comment: @Fureeish - merge sort for a linked list list does not require O(n) space. For bottom merge sort, a fixed size array of pointers to nodes is used to hold intermediate list (O(1) space). Top down merge sort for linked lists is inefficient due to scanning of lists to split them.

Comment: @rcgldr very good point, sir

Comment: @barmarkShemirani  Hi I think I am going to use quicksort but I'm concerning if quicksort raise security problems when the file I am sorting is significantly large?

Comment: And how about hashmap? will it be faster If I hash the index and make a hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array of pointers to structures would be faster than sorting a linked list of structures. If the structures aren't too big, then directly sorting an array of structures would be faster than sorting an array of pointers to structures, but this means using O(n) space (a temporary array) if using merge sort.

Since your structures have pointers to strings, merge sort should be faster than quick sort. Merge sort does more moves, but fewer compares than quick sort, and in this case, it's mostly moving pointers, but having to compare strings.

It may be faster to have fixed sized structures with maximum length allocated for the strings, so that the strings are moved during the sort. If the strings aren't too big, this will help with cache locality during the sort.

Answer (score 0):

in general, you will not need the sort criteria listed in each instance of the struct, so suggest removing those two fields.

The quickest way to sort, is to not have to perform a 'deep copy' of each of the data fields that are being pointed to by the `char*` fields.

To avoid a deep copy (and even to avoid a simple copy of the struct instances.  Develop an array of pointers to the struct instances.
Then implement something like a 'qsort()' that performs the comparisons in the fields of the struct instances, and actually only modifying the pointers to those instances.

Then traversing the sorted array by traversing the array of pointers to the struct instances.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback! But if I remove the sort criteria and Im getting the sort criteria from the command line as string, how can my program access the correct struct members?

Comment: Also isn't quicksort comes with security issue when dealing with large quantity of records? For a more stable sorting algorithm such as mergesort, wouldn't sorting an array of pointers takes more time for swapping elements (copying) than linked list?

Comment: @woshidashen, using an array of pointers, separate from the actual data, means ONLY the pointers in the array of pointers needs to be moved.  I'm not familiar with any security risk with using the quicksort function.  You could use what ever algorithm for sorting you want, including a mergesort.  Just remember that the only data movement is the pointers, so there is no need to have a linked list